# Pointer subtraction strlen

Tags: c

I don't understand the last line of sstrlen, `return t-str;`.
`str` points to `"my string"` and `t` points to `\0` so why does it work?

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t sstrlen(char *str){
    char *t = str;
    for(;*t != '\0';t++);
    return t-str; // how does it work?
}

int main()
{
    char *str = "my string";
    printf("%zu",sstrlen(str));     
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Regarding the edit: Using braces `{}` makes it clear that the body of the `for` is supposed to be empty. The semicolon could easily be a typo. Putting the semicolon on a separate line is another option.

Comment: @bruceg Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.

Comment: Use `char const *` as parameter, the string is not modified in the function. And avoid assigning literals to non-`const` `char *`, their mofication leads to Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sizeof(char)` is defined to always be `1`.  From C99:

> When applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1.

Assume that your `m` character of `my string` is stored at a memory location which is `100`. Arrays are always consecutive.

```
100 -->  m          <-- t and str point to here    
101 -->  y
102 -->  (space)
103 -->  s
104 -->  t
105 -->  r
106 -->  i
107 -->  n
108 -->  g           
109 -->  \0          <-- end of for loop t points to here
```

Subtraction address `100` pointed to by `str` from address `109` pointed to by `t` results in `9`. That's how it works.

Comment: put another way, the result of subtracting 2 pointers is the distance between the two addresses expressed in terms of the size of the things the pointers point to. In your case the distance in characters between the beginning and end of the string

Answer (score 0):

That is used to know the length of the string...
Because of while loop t will go to the end of string or character array, and when you subtract ending address with starting address you will get string length.
It's a bit faster then using index.